# Apply an IF condition to every element in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html-table

here is my problem :

I want to change a 0 by "Aucun" in all td element with the class "signalement" of a table in html and i have some troubles doing it

```
<table class="commentairesTableau">
        <tr>
            <td>N°</td>
            <td>Pseudo</td>
            <td>Message</td>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td>Signalement</td>
            <td>Validé</td>
            <td>Actions</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= htmlspecialchars($comment->getId()); ?></td>
                <td><?= htmlspecialchars($comment->getPseudo()); ?></td>
                <td><?= substr(htmlspecialchars($comment->getContent()), 0, 150); ?></td>
                <td>Créé le : <?= htmlspecialchars($comment->getCreatedAt()); ?></td>
                <td id="signalement"><?= htmlspecialchars($comment->signalement()); ?></td>
                <td id="validation"><?= htmlspecialchars($comment->signalement()); ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    if ($comment->signalement()) {
                    ?>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?route=unflagComment&commentId=<?= $comment->getId(); ?>">Désignaler le commentaire</a>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?route=deleteComment&commentId=<?= $comment->getId(); ?>">Supprimer le commentaire</a></p>
                    <?php
                    } else {
                    ?>
                        <p><a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?route=deleteComment&commentId=<?= $comment->getId(); ?>">Supprimer le commentaire</a></p>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>

if (document.getElementById("signalement").innerHTML === "0") {
    document.getElementById("signalement").innerHTML = "Aucun";
}
```

The "0" come from a boolean set in my sql database and this change only the first td line above many:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBecX.png

If someone can tell me where is my mistake and how i can fix it would be awesome !

Comment: Why don't you do it with your php? Note that element ID's must be unique by definition. Use classes for repeating elements

Comment: I already tried with class and it doesn't work at all, this project is for school and i have specific instructions and can't fix it in my php for that reason that's why i'm posting here actually, i'm really bad in javascript and i'm kinda lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can **NOT** use same id for multiple elements.

Besides that, the code which you provided, just may select all the desired elements, but will work only with the first occurrence of element with that class, and that is why, you have to loop through every occurrence, and make check.

And I will prefer to use use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`. Even though they both would result in same output, but both have their own purpose right?

Here is what you gotta do :

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".signalement").forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.innerText.trim() === "0") {
    item.innerText = "Aucun";
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="signalement"> 0 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="signalement"> 1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="signalement"> 0 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply Pranav but it actually doesn't work, maybe i have to change some things in the code?

Comment: Well thank you for your help but the problem is solved now by a very similar answer, I just looked at the difference between the answers and it taught me some interesting things, I thank you Pranav !

Answer (score 0):

You can't repeat ID's in a page, they are unique by definition. Change to classes instead then loop over all elements with that class

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.signalement').forEach(el =>{
   if(el.textContent.trim() === '0'){
      el.textContent = 'Aucun'
   }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td class="signalement"> 0 </td></tr>
    <tr><td class="signalement"> 1 </td></tr>
  <tr><td class="signalement"> 0 </td></tr>
</table>
```